# `git difftool` refuses to run under Emacs inferior shell

Tags: windows, git, emacs, cygwin, difftool

When I type [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) under plain cygwin shell, I just receive benign exit:

```
~/sb/ws> git difftool
~/sb/ws>
```

But when I type exactly the same thing under Emacs inferior shell (running the same cygwin bash), I receive the following error:

```
~/sb/ws> git difftool
git difftool
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "ENU"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
~/sb/ws>
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

(all other git commands, by the way, work perfectly under this Emacs inferior shell, so I can only assume this must be something specific to `difftool`)

**EDIT** (providing variant & version information on the tools involved):

1. cygwin-1.7.8-1
2. GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7600) of 2010-05-08 on G41R2F1
3. git version 1.7.4
4. Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Comment: What variants of Emacs and Git are you using? The Cygwin ones or native Windows? Things ought to work seamlessly with Cygwin emacs and Cygwin git.

Comment: @ak2 Thanks +1 for reminding me that I missed this information. See edit above. As I mentioned in my post, things do work seamlessly in all other regards, except for the case described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're really have wrong LANG, look onto /usr/share/locale for list of available locales..

But really question is - why're using git directly in Emacs, when it has several good git modes, and [magit](https://github.com/magit) - the best between them? Why not perform all tasks using Emacs?

P.S. I have an article about [Emacs + Git](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html)...

Comment: You have an excellent question. :)  I am in the process of learning `git` and my approach has always been to start from the command line, iron out all kinks, then upgrade to a wrapper (GUI or Emacs). Thanks for the excellent article. I must solve this mystery first, though. +1 for now.

Comment: I looked at `/usr/share/locale` and I have about 80 2-letter subdirectories. What should I be looking for? And why does it work with cygwin if I have the wrong LANG?

Comment: I just checked `git difftool` under my Emacs (under Linux only) and everything works without problem also with incorrect locale. I think, that problem is that you have no changes in directory, or you hadn't specified correct options, like name of the branch to compare, etc., for example, `git difftool HEAD~2`...  But anyway, running `git difftool` from Emacs shell isn't good idea, because Emacs terminal isn't fully functional comparing with standard terminals...

Comment: I looked at `/usr/share/locale` and despite having more than 80 2-letter subdirectories, including `en_GB`, there isn't any `en_US` and certainly not `en_US.UTF-8`. Weird.

Comment: anyway, wrong locale just lead to printing of warning, not to preventing of `git difftool` from working...

Comment: You are correct, the wrong locale just leads to printing of warning, not to preventing of git difftool from working. But I am still baffled as to why this problem only exists within Emacs. What's so special about Emacs that it requires LANG to be set in a certain way? Also, do I set it for Emacs only or for the entire environment? Where do I set it? in my .profile or via `Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings`?

Comment: you can set it explicitly from Emacs using `setenv` function

Comment: Thanks. `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` just before invoking `git difftool` did the trick. Accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Update 6 years later (2017)

> all other git commands, by the way, work perfectly under this Emacs inferior shell, so I can only assume this must be something specific to `difftool`

What is specific to `difftool` is that it is still (but not for long) written in perl: [`git-difftool.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20cf41d02158cbb838faec70ad1d989172fc592f/git-difftool.perl)

But that will change soon with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017).
That means `difftool` should run under Emacs just fine, not being bothered with Perl anymore.

See [commit 03831ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03831ef7b5011cbedbcc67abe5f47762f37c6c21) and [commit 019678d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/019678d6b1f83419cdc35e3d455175adce3a379c) (19 Jan 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).

> ### `difftool`: implement the functionality in the builtin
>
> The motivation for converting the `difftool` is that Perl scripts are not at all native on Windows, and that `git difftool` therefore is pretty slow on
>   that platform, when there is no good reason for it to be slow.
>
> In addition, Perl does not really have access to Git's internals.
>   That means that any script will always have to jump through unnecessary
>   hoops, and it will often need to perform unnecessary work (e.g. when
>   reading the entire config every time `git config` is called to query a
>   single config value).
>
> The current version of the builtin difftool does not, however, make full
>   use of the internals but instead chooses to spawn a couple of Git
>   processes, still, to make for an easier conversion. There remains a lot
>   of room for improvement, left later.
>
> Note: to play it safe, the original `difftool` is still called unless the
>   config setting `difftool.useBuiltin` is set to `true`.
>
> The reason: this new, experimental, builtin `difftool` was shipped as part
>   of Git for Windows v2.11.0, to allow for easier large-scale testing, but
>   of course as an opt-in feature.
>
> The speedup is actually more noticable on Linux than on Windows: a quick
>   test shows that [`t7800-difftool.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7800-difftool.sh) runs/
>
> - in (2.183s/0.052s/0.108s) (real/user/sys) in a Linux VM, down from  (6.529s/3.112s/0.644s), while
> - on Windows, it is (36.064s/2.730s/7.194s), down from (47.637s/2.407s/6.863s).
>
> The culprit is most likely the overhead incurred from *still* having to
>   shell out to [`mergetool-lib.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool--lib.sh) and [`difftool--helper.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-difftool--helper.sh).
>
> Still, it is an improvement.